# Build a dll for Monotouch from an iOS SDK

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm building an iOS app with Monotouch. I need to use the iOS SDK of an app called AppsFlayer or AD-X
Adeven
Adways Interactive
Apsalar
Appsflyer
CyberAgent
CyberZ
HasOffers
Kochava
Kontagent
Localytics
Septeni
Swrve
Trademob

any of the following. I can't find dll for them. My question is how can I generate a dll from an iOS SDK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Obj-C library by creating a binding for it.  Xamarin has a tool, [Objective Sharpie](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie), that helps automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

HasOffers has a Xamarin plugin now: https://github.com/MobileAppTracking/xamarin-plugin .